# Equivalent of "background-repeat: round" in SVG?

Tags: html, css, svg

CSS has a handy option for background images in HTML elements: If I have a pattern that is 20 pixels high, but my HTML element has a height that isn't evenly divisible by 20 (e.g. 150px or 35px), `background-repeat: round` will tile the pattern to make it appear seamless, stetching/squeezing the tiles as needed.

Is there an equivalent styling option for patterns within an SVG element? For example:

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="myPattern" width="200" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
        ... some pattern ...
    </pattern>
</defs>

<rect width="200" height="230" fill="#myPattern"/>
```

I'd like to have two whole repetitions of the pattern in my rectangle (stretched to 115px each), not two whole repetitions and a partial third.

**EDIT**

The [solution by ccprog (below)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48266275/67063) works fine for this particular example. However, it requires the pattern to define how many times it will be repeated. I'm still holding out hope for a general solution for cases where the elements using the pattern are of different heights (and hence will require different numbers of pattern repetitions).

Comment: @ccprog's solution is the best you are going to get. There is no automatic way in SVG to do the equivalent of `round`.  Your only other "automatic" solution would be to add some Javascript to calculate the number of repeats for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `viewBox` for patterns and define pattern units in terms of the object bounding box:

```
<defs>
    <pattern id="myPattern" width="50%" height="50%"
             viewBox="0 0 200 100" preserveAspectRatio="none"
             patternUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        ... some pattern ...
    </pattern>
</defs>

<rect width="200" height="230" fill="#myPattern"/>
```

It's not completely equivalent to CSS `round`, as you implicitely give the absolute number of repetitions with the width/height attributes, no matter how large the filled area is.